# Counting the Number of Times a Set of Years Appear in a Table?

Tags: count

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
    id VARCHAR(50),
    year VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id, year)
VALUES ('123', '2010');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id, year)
VALUES ('123', '2011');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id, year)
VALUES ('123', '2012'); 

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id, year)
VALUES ('124', '2011');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id, year)
VALUES ('124', '2012');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id, year)
VALUES ('124', '2013');


INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id, year)
VALUES ('125', '2011');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id, year)
VALUES ('125', '2012');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id, year)
VALUES ('125', '2013');

  INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id, year)
    VALUES ('127', '2011');
    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id, year)
    VALUES ('127', '2012');
    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id, year)
    VALUES ('127', '2015');

  INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id, year)
    VALUES ('126', '2019');
```

**My Question:** I am trying to find out the number of times each combination of years appears. The final result would look like this:

```
       combination freq
1   2011,2012,2015    1
2   2011,2012,2013    2
3 2010, 2011, 2012    1
4             2019    1
```

Here is my attempt at doing this in Netezza:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT id, year, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year) AS rn
    FROM MY_TABLE
),
CTE2 AS (
    SELECT id, MAX(rn) AS max_rn
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY id
),
CTE3 AS (
    SELECT CTE2.id, CTE.year, CTE.rn, CTE2.max_rn
    FROM CTE2
    JOIN CTE ON CTE2.id = CTE.id
),
CTE4 AS (
    SELECT id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN year END) ||
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN ',' || year END) ||
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN ',' || year END) ||
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN ',' || year END) ||
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN ',' || year END) ||
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 6 THEN ',' || year END) ||
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 7 THEN ',' || year END) ||
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 8 THEN ',' || year END) ||
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 9 THEN ',' || year END) ||
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 10 THEN ',' || year END)
        AS combination
    FROM CTE3
    GROUP BY id
)
SELECT combination, COUNT(*) AS freq
FROM CTE4
GROUP BY combination
ORDER BY freq DESC;
```

But the calculations are completely wrong:

```
                                       combination freq
1                                              <NA>   94
2 2010,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020    1
3 2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2019,2020    1
4 2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020    1
5 2010,2011,2012,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020    1
6 2010,2011,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020    1
7 2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019    1
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Thanks!

- **Note 1:** I am using rn = 10 to account for the min/max range of years (which in my case is 10). **I only have years 2010, 2011, ... 2020 in my dataset.** Based on this information - is it possible to write a manual solution for individual years using UNION ALL style statements?
- **Note 2:** Unfortunately, there is no GROUP_CONCAT function in Netezza - otherwise the following code would have worked:

Here is a sample:

```
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(year, ',' ORDER BY year) AS combination, COUNT(*) AS freq
    FROM my_data
    GROUP BY id
    ORDER BY freq DESC;
```

- **Note 3:** Here is R code to accomplish a similar task:

See below:

```
agg <- aggregate(year ~ id, my_table, paste, collapse = ", ")
final = as.data.frame(table(agg$year))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what functions are available in Netezza, but in PostgreSQL you can do it very simply.

```sql
SELECT
  t.years,
  COUNT(*) AS freq
FROM (
    SELECT
      array_agg(t.year) AS years
    FROM MY_TABLE t
    GROUP BY
      t.id
) t
GROUP BY
  t.years;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/DAu9RZzI)

All you need to do is find a list aggregation function, such as `STRING_AGG` `LIST_AGG` `ARRAY_AGG` etc.